# How do I check if WordprocessingDocument is empty?

Tags: .net, ms-word, ms-office

From a WordprocessingDocument how do I check if the word document is empty?

Comment: Your questions is not very specific. What do you mean with empty?

Comment: If you open some document, press Ctrl+a, Delete- there will be not data in document.

Answer (score 1):

According to the sample documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb521237(v=office.14).aspx

you can fetch the `ExtendedFilePropertiesPart` from the `WordprocessingDocument`, fetch the "Characters" property with `GetElementsByTagName("Characters")`, and if the value is zero that may be a good indicator that the document is empty, regardless of any other formatting that is present.

See the link above and scroll to the bottom of the page for the full source code.